# What does the gear icon mean in front of the network resource in Chrome DevTool's network panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome `Version 110.0.5481.77 (Official Build) (x86_64)` on macOS 13.1

I found some network resources have gear-icons before them:

[image]

I try to zoom in and notice the icon is a gear-icon.

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⚙ symbol means this request is made by a worker or a service worker ([source code](https://crsrc.org/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/core/sdk/Target.ts;l=143;drc=3106178263a854e134efc6da6470977b21a7d96c)).